# Live Facial Recognition - Mac

Tags: macos, processing, face-recognition

I'm working on a university project and I'm trying to find a Facial Recognition Software or SDK for mac, but I'm having no luck getting anything working.

I've had a play with **JavaFaces**, but this doesn't seem to be a live webcam link, it seems like it just searches through a database of pre defined images against an image you supplied. It works, but I want a webcam live recognition.

I also tried **OpenCV**, but it only seems to detect faces within Proce55ing, and not check against any pre defined images. **OpenCV 2.4.2** I can't even get to work/open, although the documentation sounds like it has a pretty awesome FR, but I don't even know if it works with Mac.

I'm a bit of an amateur coder, so I don't really know how all this importing libraries, and what'not works.

What I'm trying to do, is to have my webcam/DV cam set up, and a build/software to view the feed and scan faces that it detects, then run that face with predefined faces already saved to the computer.

Could someone please give me advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at Daniel Shiffman's blog post, [OpenCV Matching Faces Over Time](http://shiffman.net/general/2011/04/26/opencv-matching-faces-over-time/), which is a good place to start. At the end of the post he provides the full source for download in Processing.

Comment: If you are having trouble installing OpenCV on the mac, you might take a look at the [Vislab - Vision installer](http://vislab.cs.vt.edu/~vislab/wiki/index.php?title=Vision). I found a reference to it on this [post](http://codeexplode.com/setting-up-opencv-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard).